# Magento2: Error when change developer mode to production (Magento 2.1.7)

Tags: magento2, developer-mode, production-mode

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\site> php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
Enabled maintenance mode
Starting compilation
Compilation was started.
%message% 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% 1 sec 44.0 MiB%message% 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% 1 sec 44.0 MiBProxies code generation... 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% 1 sec 44.0 MiB
Proxies code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 1 sec 48.0 MiB
Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 1 sec 48.0 MiB
Repositories code generation... 2/7 [========>-------------------]  28% 34 secs 142.0 MiB
Service data attributes generation... 2/7 [========>-------------------]  28% 34 secs 142.0 MiB
Service data attributes generation... 3/7 [============>---------------]  42% 34 secs 144.0 MiB
Application code generator... 3/7 [============>---------------]  42% 34 secs 144.0 MiB
Application code generator... 4/7 [================>-----------]  57% 2 mins 160.0 MiB
Interceptors generation... 4/7 [================>-----------]  57% 2 mins 160.0 MiB
Interceptors generation... 5/7 [====================>-------]  71% 3 mins 174.0 MiB
Area configuration aggregation... 5/7 [====================>-------]  71% 3 mins 174.0 MiB
Area configuration aggregation... 6/7 [========================>---]  85% 4 mins 236.0 MiB
Interception cache generation... 6/7 [========================>---]  85% 4 mins 236.0 MiB
Interception cache generation... 7/7 [============================] 100% 5 mins 236.0 MiB

Generated code and dependency injection configuration successfully.
```

Compilation complete

Starting deployment of static content

Something went wrong while deploying static content. See the error log for details.

> Command returned non-zero exit code: `D:\xampp\php\php.exe -f D:\xampp\htdocs\site\bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US
>   ru_RU ar_SA`

Comment: Try to run command : `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` in developer mode before you set production mode!

Comment: thankyou, let me try

Comment: i guess you have issue with  memory_limit issue add -d memory_limit=10G  on static content  deploy.  `D:\xampp\php\php.exe -f  -d memory_limit=10G D:\xampp\htdocs\site\bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US ru_RU ar_SA  --force`

Comment: `php  -d memory_limit=15G bin/magento deploy:mode:set production`

Comment: @RonakChauhan: not working :(

Comment: @AmitBera: not working :(

Comment: It will show you error but with it you may find the exact error